# Equivalent to map (from haskell) in Java 7

Tags: java, haskell

In Haskell there is a function called `map`, which takes a List of Type `A` and a function `f`, mapping values of type `A` to values of type `B`. It returns a list of type `B`, such that each element of the result list originates from a call of `f` to a value in the input list.

For example, given

- a list `m = ['a', 'b', 'c']`,
- and a function `f = {'a' -> 1, 'b' -> 2, 'c' -> 3}`,
- then `map(m, f) = [1, 2, 3]`.

Is there a library, usable with Java 7, that offers something like the `map` function? I already viewed [apache CollectionUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html) and found things like [forAllDo](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#forAllDo(java.lang.Iterable,%20C)) and [transform](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#transform%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections4.Transformer%29), but they don't allow retuning a collection of a completely different type. Googling for other libraries failed for the same reason.

To be clear: I know how to solve the problem by myself, but I strongly feel that there must already exist a good library that performs this task more generally.

Bonus question: Is there some equivalent to Haskell functors (i.e. move from collections to iterables) usable in Java 7? Further explanation: Is there a map function which takes an `Iterable<A>` instead of `Collection<A>` and returns an `Iterable<B>` instead of `Collection<B>` (provided by a fitting function `f`)?

Comment: It sounds like you really want Java 8. Java 7 isn't publicly supported any more.

Comment: I have a restriction to use Java 7 in my project.

Comment: Actually there is not any function in Java 7 equivalent to Haskell. There is a java.util.Map in Java that works with key and value. The same way you can use an object into value, and so on...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are asking for Java 7 (with Java 8 it's easier):

You can use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) and there specifically [FluentIterable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html)

```
    final List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    final List<Integer> integers = FluentIterable
            .from(strings)
            .transform(new Function<String, Integer>() {
                @Nullable
                @Override
                public Integer apply(@Nullable String input) {
                    return input.equals("a") ? 1 : input.equals("b") ? 2 : input.equals("c") ? 3 : -1;
                }
            })
            .toList();
```

Bonus question: A collection is an iterable :-)

Comment: That's... actually a lot less fluent than a foreach loop.

Answer (score 4):

Functional transformations were added to Java 8 and they are not available for Java 7. For example, a map function that transforms a String to an integer looks like this Java 8

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1","2","3");
List<Integer> nums = list.stream().map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Unlike Haskell, Java collections are strict, however `Streams` ( Java 8) are `lifted` ( ~ lazy).

There are libraries that support `higher order functions` for `Java 7` like `Guava`. Guava has a `transform` function that transforms T -> U, for ex:

```
Collection<Integer> ints = Collections2.transform(list, new Function<String, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer apply(String s) {
            return Integer.parseInt(s);
        }
    });
```

But as you can tell ,due to the lack of lambda expressions in Java 7, it doesn't look concise

Answer (score 3):

You can write yourself an `Iterator` that takes a `map` object that does the transformation.

```
static class Transformer<F, T> implements Iterator<T> {

    final Iterator<F> source;
    final Map<F, T> map;

    public Transformer(Iterator<F> source, Map<F, T> map) {
        this.source = source;
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return source.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        return map.map(source.next());
    }

    public interface Map<F, T> {

        public T map(F f);
    }
}

private static final String[] numbers = {"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};

public void test() {
    List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    Transformer t = new Transformer<>(ints.iterator(), new Transformer.Map<Integer, String>() {
        @Override
        public String map(Integer f) {
            return numbers[f];
        }

    });
    while (t.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(t.next());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need use Stream APi from Java 8. Using official API you cann't using Stream APi in Java 7, but using:

1. [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda),
2. [totallylazy](https://github.com/bodar/totallylazy),
3. [gradle-retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda), or
4. [Lightweight-Stream-API](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API)

you can. More info see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30055585/java-streams-in-java-7) and documentation retrolambda, totallylazy, gradle-retrolambda or  Lightweight-Stream-API. But if you can using Java 8, it's much more easy than using non official API.

Or you can use

5. [FunctionalExplained Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained)
6. [Functional Java lib](http://www.functionaljava.org/)

to use functional programming in Java 7, but Stream API more offical and general.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know such a library, but what is wrong using the plain java, like:

```
List<String> m;
Map<Key,String> map = new HashMap<Key,String>();
int c=1;
for (String i : m) map.put(i,c++);
```