# Is there any aggregate-type or select-type functions built into Java 7?

Tags: java, aggregate-functions, java-7

Consider this function which sums the results of a range of values passed to a function...

```
int totalColumnWidth = 0;
for(int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnCount; columnIndex++)
    totalColumnWidth += getWidthForColumn(columnIndex);
```

It just seems so verbose!  In other languages, I can do that in one line, which has the added benefit of allowing me to make totalColumnWidth read-only.  Is there any such thing in Java 7 (we're doing Android development for KitKat API 19).

My guess is 'no' since I understand Java 7 doesn't support lambdas which are needed for this type of functionality (you'd have to pass in the `getWidthForColumn()` call), but I'd love to be mistaken.

Comment: You're correct. This is easy to create in **Java 8** but not in **Java 7**.

Comment: I'm not convinced 3 lines of code is verbose (but I guess you are showing us a simplified version of your 'real' code)! Anyway, to answer your question, Sorry no - you need Java 8 for this

Comment: or Kotlin, which is quite popular on Android, for that reason among others, and runs on Java 6.

Comment: There are some libraries that can do that see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30055585/java-streams-in-java-7 and you can find some more with a simple google 'java 7 streams'

Comment: Someone please put this in an answer so I can mark it as closed. :)

Comment: I flagged as duplicate, you can close it with that if you like. An answer would be link only.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. **Java 7** does not support such functionalities by default. It can easily be created with **Java 8** though.

However there are some libraries which provide similar methods or emulate lambdas. Therefore also see [SO: java streams in Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30055585/java-streams-in-java-7) (as stated by @Oleg).